# c# JSON API and XML feed, but need to filter some results out...use string.Replace?

Tags: c#, xml, json, api

I have built a REST API returning JSON for one part of my application... Here it returns a list of vehicles with the vehicles specs.  There is a list of "Features" which are bool fields on each vehicle.  What im trying to achieve in the XML feed I provide in another part of the solution, is to only display the features that are present and NOT to display the ones that return false.

My XML is formed by the following code:

```
        var rawApiResponse = GetRawApiResponse(URLForAPI);

        //Convert the JSON returned result to XML

        var xmlDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(rawApiResponse, "DealersStock");
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        var xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
        xmlDocument.WriteTo(xw);

        return Content(sw.ToString(), "text/xml");
```

I was wondering what the best way to remove the unwanted returned values in XML?

I was thinking along the lines of write to string and use

```
string.Replace("<Feature1>false</Feature1>", "")
```

or is there a better way of handling the XML at this point?

Or should I be doing this at the API level of the application?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to do it where you retrieve the data. Something like

```
v.Features.Where(f => f)
```

edit:

Given a IEnumerable< Vehicle > x, you can enumerate it and select just the "true" features

```
foreach (var v in x)
  v.Features = v.Features.Where(f => f);
```

(you can create a new IEnumerable if you don't want to change de data in the original collection for some reason)

Comment: many thanks for your fast response, so you would suggest that I make the filter on the API request where the data is being populated.. not sure this will entirely work as will filter out results based on the features, but i'll give it a go and see what I can do :)

Comment: Note that the where condition is applied on the Features property, not on the "x" variable. I'll edit with an example.